# Can .NET memory leak cause port exhaustion?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, windows-server-2008

We have an ASP MVC application (C#) and our web server has been having an issue due to port exhaustion. This happens every 2 weeks and a reboot fixes the issue. But I want to get to the bottom of this issue and find a permanent fix to avoid the reboots.

I read [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/10/29/port-exhaustion-and-you-or-why-the-netstat-tool-is-your-friend/) and it was really useful. However, it mentions this:

> So, if you see a process that’s using up a lot of ports, talking to a single remote address or several remote addresses, and the state of the connection is something like TIME_WAIT, that’s usually a dead giveaway that this process is having a problem and **not releasing those ports properly**.

(Emphasis Mine)

Then further down there is this paragraph:

> I mentioned above that memory leaks can cause this behavior too – why is that exactly? What happens is that in order to get a port to use for an outbound connection, processes need to acquire a handle to that port. That handle comes out of non-paged pool memory. So, if you have a memory leak, and you run out of non-paged pool, processes that need to talk to other machines on the network won’t be able to get the handle, and therefore won’t be able to get the port they need.

**Questions**:

1. What does the author mean by *not releasing those ports properly*? Whose job is that, the programmer?
2. Can someone please elaborate how a memory leak could cause *port exhaustion* because I am still not sure after reading the above?

One last thing to keep in mind is that I am a programmer and not an administrator (if that helps in anyway possible).

Comment: "Port exhaustion" as in running out of network ports? You probably want to close your ports explicitly rather than hoping they get cleaned up for you. Without code it's hard to say where the problem is.

Comment: Have you even found evidence to support that your application is leaking memory?

Comment: @tadman It is a huge application and I have not dived into the code yet to look for memory leaks so posting code is out of the question. I am interested in knowing if memory leak can cause port exhaustion and how?

Comment: It could if you're creating large circular data structures the garbage collector won't collect and those structures have associated network resources attached. If you're depending on collection for closing network handles you may have a problem. The solution is explicitly closing them.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto My question is not about whether our application has memory leak (I have not looked into that yet). Please see comment above and read my question again because I am asking something else.

Comment: Are you using `HttpClient` in any using statements?  This class is an oddity in that MSDN recommends that you create a static instance of this and reuse vs using in `using` statements as doesn't really dispose of things like it should. (https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: Ok I see the votes piling to close this question. Can you please suggest which site I should post this question on then?

Comment: If it's "memory leak" as in "not disposing objects correctly", it could be. But there are many ways for this to happen, making this too broad

Comment: @Tommy We do not use `using` in any of those cases because yes, you are correct, they cause leaks. Again my question is not about memory leaks and how to avoid it.

Comment: @CodingYoshi - Good deal.  I would still do a code audit for any of your `HttpClient` calls to ensure one is not being spun up somewhere you are not expecting.  The results of the article listed sound much like what you are experiencing.  For instance, declaring a new `HttpClient` instance in class constructors could lead to a bunch of these things sitting around.

Comment: The author is not saying memory leaks cause port exhaustion. He is saying that memory leaks and port exhaustion can have many of the same symptoms. This because getting a handle to a port requires memory allocation. There is a separate limit on the number of ports. If you are unable to get a handle to a port because you are hitting the limit on the number of ports that's port exhaustion. If it's because you can't allocate the memory for the handle, that's likely a memory leak.

Comment: Memory leak and port exhaustion are independent. You have to analyze them separately, but both are too broad to be discussed here. If you can afford, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com